# WebAssembly language with small footprint

Tags: webassembly

I'm looking for a language that is compiled to wasm (or to something else that's not human-readable and run through web assembly, like a dll), with a small footprint. I need to be able to interact with it from javascript.

What I need it for is to perform hashing of a string in a way a user wouldn't be able to easily figure out. I know anything that runs on the client is not secure, but it's a deterrent, not a security feature (like a captcha).

I have already done this with Blazor, but the download size is too large, so I'm looking for something that has a smaller footprint.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One lightweight way to target WebAssebmly is https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript.   It's low level but more easy to write that raw WebAssembly.    if you are careful to avoid dependencies on the larger parts of libc, then emscripten can also produce very small binary files.

However, if your goal is obfuscation then WebAssebmly is really not better than JavaScript.  WebAssembly was not designed for this purpose.  As with something like the JVM bytecode there are tools out there are do good job of decompiling WebAssembly binaries.  See wasm-deompile which is part of https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt.  These tools will only get better over time.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that out. And yes, I realize it's still possible to decompile, but that's at least a little bit harder than just searching the source.