# Virtual Machines/Programming Languages with small binary footprints (kilobytes)

Tags: list, virtual-machine, programming-languages

I'm looking for (high level) languages whose compiled files have a very small footprint, such that they could be *stored* in a QR code or small microcontroller memory - just several Kilobytes at most for programs like Hello World or drawing graphics.

The more features the environment this code runs on provides, the more compact it can be. So far I found:

- [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) languages source code.
- [Java](https://medium.com/@davethomas_9528/writing-hello-world-in-java-byte-code-34f75428e0ad) seems also relatively compact
- [AssemblyScript](https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript) for [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/) (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248582/webassembly-language-with-small-footprint) question)

Answer (score 2):

AssemblyScript as language + [wasm3](https://github.com/wasm3/wasm3) as runtime could be the best choice I guess. See this examples for Arduino: https://github.com/wasm3/wasm3-arduino